# Writing a promise to work with a callback that passes two arguments

Tags: javascript, promise, web-sql, babeljs

In a recent cordova app at work, we used the WebSQL api, as it gave us the device support and functionality needed to store data locally. We're going to use it again for an upcoming project, so I started exploring promises with [implemented in core.js, using BabelJS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/core-js#ecmascript-6-promises). **edit** added link to promises implementation.

Here's what i have so far:

```
function getConnection () {
  return window.openDatabase("cfa.db", "1.0", "CFA Database", 1000000);
}

function executeSql (transaction, query, args) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log(query);
    transaction.executeSql(query, args, resolve, reject);
  });
}

function transaction (connection) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    connection.transaction(resolve, reject);
  });
}

class DataSource {
  executeSql (query, args) {
    var connection = getConnection();
    transaction(connection).then((tx) => {
      return executeSql(tx, query, args);
    }).then((tx, res) => {
      console.log(tx, res.rows.length);
    }, (tx, e) => {
      console.log(e);
    });
  }
}
```

And here's the barebones on doing a simple query with the api itself:

```
var connection = getConnection();
connection.transaction(function (tx, res) {
  tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM table", [], function (tx, res) {
    console.log(res.rows.length);
  }, function (tx, err) {
    console.log(err);
  });
}, function (err) {
  console.log(err);
});
```

So the transaction simply passes the transaction instance, which i can use to execute a sql statement on. That was simple enough to wrap in a promise. The trickier part is the callbacks for the `executeSql` method. It passes the transaction, which is nice to use for additional queries. Then it passes the result data. How can I wrap this in a promise?

In my `DataSource` class, the executeSql method there logs a transaction object, but no res object. The transaction then fires correctly, and returning the promise should work. But I respect that it only returns the first parameter. How  can I get around this?

Comment: Can you wrap that callback into a function that returns one combine result?

Comment: You mean have the transaction and execute sql in a single promise?

Comment: @agmcleod be sure to use the _lastest_ version with updated core-js, more debuggable promises have only landed 22 hours ago https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/issues/12 :) In either case if your app runs on a phone I _warmly_ recommend bluebird in favor of core-js. Enjoy the fact you're not that memory constrained and opt for a stronger, faster and more debuggable implementation. You can tell babel to compile async functions to it with the bluebird-coroutine flag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `executeSql` method you pass `resolve` to the `transaction.executeSQL` method.

Promises are like normal values - you can't return multiple values from a function - just like you can't resolve a promise with multiple values. Your options are either to resolve it with a `[transaction, response]` array (and use babeljs's ES6 destructuring assignments) or to resolve with just one argument. In your case it's clear you're only interested in the response.

```
function executeSQL(transaction, query, args){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
        transaction.executeSQL(query, args, (t,r) => resolve(r), reject);
    );
}
```

Note that you can refactor your `DataSource` class to:

```
class DataSource{
    async executeSQL(query, args){
        let connection = getConnection();
        let transaction = await transaction(connection);
        let result = await executeSQL(transaction, query, args);
        return result; // or console.log result.rows.length
    }
}
```

You don't need to pass the transaction around here since you already have it and the problem it solves for you (context passing) doesn't exist with promises.

Comment: I'll give this a try. I'm actually interested in both, because getting the transaction back will make it easier to chain queries if i need to. Easy enough to edit your example there with an array.

Comment: @agmcleod just be sure to use the array destructuring syntax - I can add an example of doing that to the answer if you'd like.

Comment: Thanks again. Given the ES7 is experimental in the compiler, is it worth using for something that will ship to clients? I do like the cleanliness of it all though :)

Comment: Yes - you're using the build step anyway might as well make the best of it

Answer (score 1):

Since your intent is to provide both values as part of the promise result, I'd propose wrapping them in an object so that they can be extracted by whoever receives it:

```
function executeSql (transaction, query, args) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        console.log(query);
        transaction.executeSql(query, args, (t, r) => resolve({ 
            transaction: t, 
            result: r
        }), reject);
    });
}
```

Usage:

```
transaction(connection)
.then(tx => executeSql(tx, query, args))
.then({result} => console.log(tx, result.rows.length), 
      e => console.log(e)
);
```

Comment: ES6 arrow functions allow omitting the `{}`s and `return` if it's a one liner so `(tx) => { return executeSQL(tx, query, args); }` can really be `tx => executeSQL(tx, query, args)`. Also - you can use object destructuring in the second then.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Thanks. Did I get the destructuring right? I've actually never touched ES6.

Comment: Yes, looks good to me, you can destructure even more levels but to be fair I'm not sure if that's allowed by ES6 or just babel.